# Usage of "He was to XXX"

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I found it in a Grammar quiz online which I forget where it is:

> Mr Jones ____ at the meeting, but he had to cancel because of his illness.
>
> a) was speaking
>
> b) was to speak
>
> c) was to have spoken

The answer is c, and I am Ok with it, but I don't know why b isn't. Can't I say someone was to do something, **but** he could't somehow?

Comment: Infinitives don't specify the tense of the verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B and c are both fine. The difference is not in the circumstances described: as with most uses of the perfect, the difference is in how the speaker is choosing to refer to the events. In c) the temporal focus is after the meeting; in b) the temporal focus is not specified - might be now, or might be just before the meeting.

Comment: Answer a) ticks my ears. Can't it be used?

Comment: @Ustanak How can you be speaking and cancel your speech at the same time? Without other context, "cancel" is assumed to refer to the speech.

Comment: Actually, now I think of it, I can image a) being used. I can say "I'm speaking at the meeting tomorrow" because I intend to, not knowing whether something might cause this not to happen. In the same way, if the temporal focus is before he got ill, I might say "He was speaking at the meeting" in the same sense.

Comment: @user3169 Oh, I must've been tripped. That's right.

Comment: @ColinFine Then my gut feeling was right. However, is it acceptable to use a) anyway?

Comment: @Ustanak: "Acceptable" is a social judgment, and I am not interested in those. I believe that people do use it in that way; I think it is clearer to use b).